# React Get json to const variable from API

Tags: reactjs, json, api

I have React app to build folder tree structure from json:

> Treelist Page

```
const treeData = [{here is my json}];

const TreeList = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header title="Tree Data Visualization" />
      <ExternalInfo page="treeList" />
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col text-center">
            <div className="row mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
              <div className="col-lg-8 text-left text-dark">
                  <Tree data = {treeData}/>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TreeList;
```

> Treelist Component

```
const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {data.map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const TreeNode = ({ node }) => {
  const [childVisible, setChildVisiblity] = useState(false);
  const hasChild = node.elements ? true : false;
  const hasChildelements = node.elements ? true : false;
  const hasNodeDescription = node.description ? true : false;

  return (
    <li className="d-tree-node border-0">
      <div className="d-flex" onClick={(e) => setChildVisiblity((v) => !v)}>
        {hasChild && (
          <div
            className={`d-inline d-tree-toggler ${
              childVisible ? "active" : ""
            }`}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon="caret-right" />
          </div>
        )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default Tree;
```

Everything here works fine, until I try to get const json from API. I have tried all the solutions I can find in the internet.
Example API I try to get json from:
https://someapi.free.beeceptor.com/

Answer (score 0):

The treeData you provide to Tree component in the first snippet seems to be structured differently on the API you want to consume. See that your treeData is an array but the what API gives you is an object. You may use the array part of it, namely the directories property.

Comment: Hello I have copied json from API to const and have such result. A have also tried to get array from object

Comment: https://im.ge/i/ut65T0

Comment: Can you please share your code that fetches the data?

Comment: 'function App(){
   const [treeData, setData] = React.useState({});
   React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://someapi.free.beeceptor.com/')
         .then(response => setData(response.json()))
         .then(data => console.log(data));
   },[])
   return (<Tree data = {treeData}/>)
   } 
'

Comment: I have also changed this part

Comment: const Tree = ({ data = [] }) => {
  return (
    <div className="d-tree">
      <ul className="d-flex d-tree-container flex-column">
        {Array.from(data).map((tree) => (
          <TreeNode node={tree} />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

Comment: I get no errors console and output are blank

Comment: I also tried this: return (<Tree data = {data.data}/>). It gives me an array of length 0